# Getting a shortcode button to stick to the bottom-center of a window/page section

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

This is my first question so I hope I'm doing this right!

Basically, I'm building a website using wordpress as the CMS (using the artbees Jupiter theme: http://artbees.net/themes/jupiter/), and I need to get a shortcode button to stick to the bottom of the page section and be mobile responsive. That is, for a specific section of the page, I need the button to stick to the bottom of the screen.

I made an example here using a "scroll to bottom" arrow feature they already have in the theme, except this one scrolls instead of links to another page: http://explosiveleads.net/about/

As you can see, the arrow sticks to the bottom of the "page section" no matter what (although, I'd want the button below the text, not out of the screen.

So I've tried about a billion options already.
The closest I got was by creating a custom class for the button called "bottombutton" and putting this in the custom css:

```
.bottombutton {
position:fixed;
bottom:10px;
}
```

However, this offsets the button from the center to the right, and then is negated when viewed on a mobile device.

If I do this:

```
.bottombutton {
position:fixed
bottom:5%
right:50%
}
```

It just goes spazz on me and sticks it still off center.

In a desperate effort, I emailed the creators of the theme and asked for help. The told me: "Unfortunately it is not possible to do such a thing with CSS only. We also did it with Javascript for the arrow you mentioned"

However, I am not sure how to do it with javascript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
If any other info is needed just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Before answering, I'm not good at English that you would be hard to understand my English.

But I will try.

.

I'll give you one of the many ways in javascript to fixing button on bottom.

First, you need to catch event when the page scroll

```
window.onscroll = function(){}
```

Second, make function what can fixing button on bottom.

```
var fixedButton = document.getElementsByClassName("bottombutton")[0];
    fixedButton.style.position = "absolute";
    fixedButton.style.top = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - parseInt(fixedButton.style.height);
```

Third, merge it.

```
window.onscroll = function(){
    var fixedButton = document.getElementsByClassName("bottombutton")[0];
    fixedButton.style.position = "absolute";
    fixedButton.style.top = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - parseInt(fixedButton.style.height);
}
```

Finally you can see the sticky button on bottom.
But I recommend to you jQuery javascript plugin.
http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/07/using-jquery-to-add-a-dynamic-back-to-top-floating-button-with-smooth-scroll/

Thanks.

---

Sorry m.m I fixed some code

This will work well.

```
window.onscroll = function(){
    var fixedButton = document.getElementsByClassName("bottombutton")[0];
    fixedButton.style.position = "absolute";
    fixedButton.style.top = document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight - fixedButton.offsetHeight + "px";
}
```

---

**jQuery** source for your homepage

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.bottombutton').centerBottom();
});
$.fn.centerBottom = function () {
    $(this).css("position", "absolute");
    $(this).css("top", Math.max(0, $(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    $(this).css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2)) + "px");
    return $(this);
};
```

it will work on your mobile device

Comment: Hi HansolLim, this doesn't seem to work.
The button becomes centered in the page, and then jumps the right upon scrolling. Any ideas?

Comment: **Omg!!** sorry I have a mistake.

Comment: Hi HansolLim,
I adjusted to code as you suggested, but it still isn't working.
The button is in the middle of the page instead of at the bottom.
Like this: http://www.explosiveleads.net/home-2

It's driving me crazy! ahaha

Comment: ah! your homepage is including jQuery.
I'll add jQuery source on my post

Comment: basically you should add <!DOCTYPE HTML> in your HTML file

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by creating the following custom css class and linking it to the button:

```
.bottom2 { 
position: fixed;   
display: table;   
left: 50%;   
cursor: pointer;   
bottom: 0;   
margin: -26px 0 16px -125px;   
width: 250px;   
height: 20px;   
border-radius: 50%;   
text-align: center;   
opacity: 1;}
```

Thanks for all your help!